# PySimpleGUI make only the window transparent

Tags: pysimplegui

I want to make all elements except for the window visible (for custom close buttons instead of default), but alpha_channel makes the whole GUI transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alpha_channel` sets the opacity of the window.

Try the option `transparent_color`

- any portion of the window that has this color will be completely transparent. You can even click through these spots to the window under this window.

With option `no_titlebar=True`, no titlebar nor frame will be shown on window.

Refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/150#issuecomment-1022241469

```py
from ctypes import windll

import PySimpleGUI as sg

GWL_EXSTYLE = -20
WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080


if hasattr(windll.user32, "GetWindowLongPtrW"):
    _get_window_style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrW
    _set_window_style = windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW
else:
    _get_window_style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW
    _set_window_style = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW


class MyWindow(sg.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, no_titlebar=False, **kwargs):
        self._no_titlebar = no_titlebar
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def Finalize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().Finalize(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._no_titlebar:
            self.normal()

    def minimize(self):
        if self._no_titlebar:
            root = self.TKroot
            # clear override or Tcl will raise an error
            root.overrideredirect(False)
            # redraw the window to have something to show in the taskbar
            self.refresh()
            # catch the deinconify event
            root.bind("<Map>", self.normal)

        super().minimize()

    def normal(self, event=None):
        if self._no_titlebar:
            root = self.TKroot
            # set override to remove the titlebar
            root.overrideredirect(True)
            # set exstyle so that it shows in the taskbar
            hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
            style = _get_window_style(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
            style &= ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
            style |= WS_EX_APPWINDOW
            _set_window_style(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
            # avoid infinite loop (withdraw + deiconify triggers a <Map>)
            root.unbind("<Map>")
            # re-assert window style
            root.withdraw()

        super().normal()


layout = [[sg.B("X"), sg.B("_")]]
window = MyWindow("test", layout, no_titlebar=True, size=(200, 100), finalize=True)

while True:
    event, _ = window.read()

    if event == "X":
        break

    elif event == "_":
        window.minimize()

window.close()
```

Note: If nothing wrong, it may only work on Windows platform.

Comment: Just another thing, although not necessary is it possible to hide the default bar that contains the close, minimise and maximise buttons?

Comment: Updated as above.